No ObservableObject of type SettingsNavigator found. A View.environmentObject(_:) for SettingsNavigator may be missing as an ancestor of this view
I get this error while setting navigation for settings page. I still tried some similar kind of suggestions, but that didn't helped me.
This is my settingsNavigator
import SwiftUI

final class SettingsNavigator: ObservableObject, Navigator {
    typealias Destination = SettingsDestination
    @Published var path = NavigationPath()
}

public enum SettingsDestination: Codable, Hashable {
    case accountPrivacyAndSettingScreen
    case likeAndCommentSettingsScreen

}


this is my setting navigation
public struct VSettingsNavigation: View {
    @StateObject var router = SettingsNavigator()
//    @ObservedObject var settingsViewModel: SettingsViewModel

    public var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $router.path) {
            VSettings()
                .navigationDestination(for: SettingsDestination.self) { destination in
                    switch destination {
                    case .accountPrivacyAndSettingScreen: VAccountPrivacyAndSettings().navigationBarBackButtonHidden()
                    case .likeAndCommentSettingsScreen: VLikeAndCommentSettings().navigationBarBackButtonHidden()
                    case .notificationSettingsScreen: V
                .accentColor(.white)
                .navigationBarBackButtonHidden()
                .environmentObject(router)
        }
    }
}


and this is setting view
struct VSettings: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var settingsNavigator: SettingsNavigator
    @State private var showLogoutConfirmation = false

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.black
                .ignoresSafeArea()

            VStack {
                HStack {
                    Text("Settings")
                        .font(.system(size: 18, design: .default))
                        .foregroundColor(.white)

                    Spacer()
                    Spacer().frame(width: 44)
                }
                .padding()

                ScrollView {
                    ForEach(settingOption) { setting in
                        Button(action: {
                            settingsNavigator.navigate(to: setting.path ?? .aboutScreen)

                        }) {
                            SettingOptionRow(setting: setting)
                        }
                    }
                }

            }.padding()
        }
    }
}

I saw some similar questions, but couldnt solve it.b hOw to fix this issue?

You would get this error, if VSettings view (in the body of VSettingsNavigation view) wouldn't have been modified with .environmentObject(router).  However, according your code, you did apply the modifier. Obviously, your code doesn't show everything. I would suggest to remove everything that's irrelevant and provide the rest as a minimal reproductive example, if you not already found the issue yourself by doing this. ;)

you shouldn't need a router object
